# How to use Ruby 1.9.3 in Cloubdees?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3, cloudbees

My build on Cloudbees fail. For some reason, it is using a file named 'use-ruby' to install Ruby 1.8.7.

Since I use and require 1.9.3, it is always failing. Is there a way to overide that file and get 1.9.3 instead?

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Ruby+Builds on the way to use ruby add-ons to select the version of ruby interpreter to be used for your build